# Java command line angle brackets

Tags: java, command-line, io

How do you read from and write to files passed on the command line using the < and > symbols?

This is the command: `java Main < input.txt > output.txt`

So I want to know what the code in the java file will look like. How do I reference these files?

Just to clarify, I can use files no problem if passed with: `java Main input.txt output.txt`
but I'm currently constrained to using the angle brackets.

Comment: Why are you constrained to the angle brackets? I know the `>` has a special meaning as to output the results to the proceeding file path. That could cause some conflicts with your constraints.

Comment: I have to use them in a college assignment. I need to compress a file, but cannot explicitly open or close files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about Linux/Unix/Bsd ...

The `<` and `>` redirections are handled by the shell itself.  By the time your Java application is called, the shell has already figured out what the pathnames resolve to, opened them, and connected them to the file descriptors used for `System.in` and `System.out`.

So you just code your program to read from `System.in` and write to `System.out`.

(The same principle applies if your application is part of a pipeline, and if FD #2 is redirected, that will be connected to `System.err`.  The only thing that is not straightforward is if you do something unusual like this:

```
   java Main < input.txt 3> output.txt
```

That will redirect FD #3 to a file.  AFAIK, there is no simple way to write to FD's beyond 2 from Java.)

Comment: I tested this out (in Windows) and you're right. I found nothing about this from searching online, so thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

These operators mean that you want to **read** the input from `input.txt` and **write** the result to `output.txt`.

Comment: As I'm looking back now at my old questions, I realise that not only was your answer unhelpful (since I named the files that way intentionally), but it downright ignored the question being asked (which was about how to read the files in the java class). Poor show!

Comment: @ConorPender Your comment can be more constructive than using rich phrases like "poor show". I wanted to help, I might misunderstood the question but your question is not that clear.

Comment: @ConorPender Learn how to comment in order to improve things.

Comment: And by the way, I wasn't making you any shows. Just in case you thought so.

Answer (score 1):

Following normal conventions, `<` is `System.in` and `>` is `System.out`. <s>However, passing just a String to System.in probably does not do what you expect it to in this case</s>